# Flip a scaled and rotated uiview in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am trying to flip a scaled and rotated uiview on the horizontal axis.
Here is the code being used -

```
CGFloat xScale = selectedFrame.transform.a;
CGFloat yScale = selectedFrame.transform.d;
selectedFrame.layer.transform = CATransform3DScale(CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0),xScale, yScale,-1);
```

The output of this is that the view flips properly and the original scale factor is also manitained but the rotation isnt.
Here are the images to explain the problem -

Original Image (The tiger view has to be flipped on the horizontal axis) - 
[image: http://cloudart.com.au/projects/appscreenshots/Original_image.png]

Flipped image after above code (see that the scale is maintained but the rotation angle isnt and the image s flipped properly) -
[image: http://cloudart.com.au/projects/appscreenshots/Flipped_image.png]

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To flip the image you are using a rotation of M_PI around the Y axis. To rotate the image, you need to apply another different rotation around the Z axis. These are two different transforms. You can combine them using CATransform3DConcat. Then you can scale the resulting transform.

```
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DConcat(CATransform3DMakeRotation(zRotation, 0, 0, 1),CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI, 0, 1, 0));
[layer setTransform:CATransform3DScale(transform,xScale, yScale,1)];
```

The problem with your original code is that you are only applying the Y axis transform.

I'm sure there is a more elegant way to do this, but this works on my simulator.

Comment: That doesnt work and messes up the flip working right now as well.

Comment: After looking at your question again, I've changed the answer.

Comment: may I ask, what is parameter "zRotation"? Thank you very much

Comment: zRotation should be set to the desired rotation angle for the image

Comment: What if I need to transform all axis'? X, Y and Z. CATransform3DConcat seems to take only 2.

Comment: @durazno I'd recommend you open another question